# Oracle Database on Docker is very, very slow

Tags: oracle, docker

I created one Oracle Database on Docker based on the instruction and dockerfile in the following website.

https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase

After image is created and I run

```
docker run --name oracle -p 1521:1521 -p 5500:5500 -e ORACLE_SID=ORCLCDB -e ORACLE_PDB=ORCLPDB1 oracle/database:12.1.0.2-ee
```

to start a oracle container. But it is terribly slow.

The following is log:

```
...

Starting /opt/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
System parameter file is /opt/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/c88078b7a26e/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                04-SEP-2016 21:04:43
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /opt/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/c88078b7a26e/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
Copying database files
1% complete
2% complete
27% complete
Creating and starting Oracle instance
29% complete
32% complete
33% complete
34% complete
38% complete
42% complete
43% complete
45% complete
Completing Database Creation
48% complete
51% complete
53% complete
62% complete
64% complete
72% complete
Creating Pluggable Databases
78% complete
100% complete
```

Anyone can tell me how I can speed it up. It took 20min to finish.
I saw a message at the end of this log, not sure whether it is related to slowness or not.

> Default pga_aggregate_limit value is too high for the
> amount of physical memory in the system
> pga_aggregate_limit is 2048 MB
> limit based on physical memory and SGA usage is 2020 MB

Comment: I'm not sure if you are saying that starting the Docker container is slow, that the Oracle database itself is slow, or something else.  If you are saying that the Oracle database itself is slow, given the error message, I would suspect that the database was configured to use more memory than your particular machine can really tolerate.

Comment: Oracle database  itself slow, from 1% to 100% it took 20 mins. Thanks for reformat it, it is more readable now.

Comment: "1% to 100% it took 20 minutes" is talking about the time to start the Docker container not anything specific to the Oracle database itself.  But you're saying that the Oracle database itself is slow which implies that you are running queries and it is taking too long for some definition of "too long".

Comment: It is part of oracle starting process, if you count it as docker start, then it is.

Comment: "copying database files", "creating Oracle instance", "creating pluggable databases", etc. are not things that are normally done to start up an Oracle database.  You're presumably using the 12.1 enterprise edition database.  If you are concerned about startup time, you may want the express edition database.

Comment: I have been using oracle in non docker config, and donot see those steps, not sure why oracle in docker env need those steps and want to understand why it is slow.I hope someone from that github link to answer my question. if anyone know how to post a question against  that link, please help thanks.

Comment: Well, there is an issue logged against the github project about making the instance persistent which, presumably, would eliminate the need to do a full install every time.  https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues/141  It sounds like that is not currently possible with that particular Docker container.

Comment: Thanks, this is answer I want.

Answer (score 5):

I managed to drop DB startup time significantly. The idea is to take a snapshot of the already configured and running database. More information and step by step guide can be found here: https://medium.com/@ggajos/drop-db-startup-time-from-45-to-3-minutes-in-dockerized-oracle-19-3-0-552068593deb

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues/141
The slowness due to the installation step.
Thanks Justin Cave for prompt help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom Dockerfile based on Oracle image pro other. I've prepared for my idę case a image which Dora not.require this setup step. You can see https://github.com/KamilJedrzejuk/oracle18c-xe

Answer (score 0):

[This image](https://hub.docker.com/r/gvenzl/oracle-xe) starts approximately 2 minutes

Specifically, it is gvenzl/oracle-xe. I am using 10 CPU M1 Apple Sillicon, consequently, someone can wait more extended time.